# Model object in spring get null value when refreshing the page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sprite

In the controller class I have a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newQuestion/{questionId}",method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String newQuestion(@PathVariable("questionId") String questionId, Model model,@ModelAttribute("quest") Quest quest ) {


        Question question = new Question();
        question.setName("New Question");
        model.addAttribute("quest", quest);
        model.addAttribute("question", question);
        return "newQuestion";
    }
```

This is redirected from one page and gets value of quest object from this page.

I get the quest object correctly after redirecting, but get gets lost after refreshing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call this controller method by using `GET`; in a `GET` request a `@ModelAttribute` object such as `quest` will be `null`.

Comment: i have a doubt, when if a controller method returns a string is it redirect or forward?

Comment: Controller forwards the request to JSP.

Comment: my the url gets changed after the controller method, i believe it is a redirect

Comment: yes u r right its forwards the request and here im using alredy forwarded to this page so i get @ModelAttribute("quest") while redirecting losts after refreshing...